# MSTest Data driven test not running all rows

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest, data-driven-tests

I'm using VS2015, and writing tests in MSTest. It seems that MSTest doesn't run all rows in a data driven test
for example, this is a sample test:

```
//there is a XML datafile that has 1000 "rows", 1 to 1000
int x = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["Payload"]);
if (x == 999)
    throw new Exception();
```

When i debug the test, it correctly fails at 999. However, when I run the test (not debug) the test result says (most of the time) that the test has passed. The details for the test show that not all 1000 rows were tested.
Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Note: this issue happens most of the time. once in a blue moon, the test result seems to have run all 1000 rows, and shows the failed test correctly.

mcve as requested:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestDataDriven
{
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContextInstance; }
        set { testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    [TestMethod]        
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
               "data.xml",
               "Row",
                DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        int x = Int32.Parse((string)TestContext.DataRow["Payload"]);
        if (x == 999)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

make sure to have an xml file in this format in build location

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Iterations>
  <Row>
    <Payload>1</Payload>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Payload>2</Payload>
  </Row>
.
.
.
  <Row>
    <Payload>1000</Payload>
  </Row>
</Iterations>
```

Note: if you are willing to do so, you can get MSTestHacks from NuGet, then the following is somewhat easier code, in that you wont need to generate the data file.

```
namespace Namespace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestDataDriven : TestBase
    {
        List<int> _source = new List<int>( Enumerable.Range(1,1000));
        public List<int> Source
        {
            get { return _source; }
            set { _source = value; }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("Namespace.TestDataDriven.Source")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var x = TestContext.GetRuntimeDataSourceObject<int>();
            if (x == 999)
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just added an mcve. whether by mstest iteslf or mstesthacks, i still have the issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue driving from sql server

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Was anyone able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Three years in.... 
Solution? Switch to xunit. I've come to the conclusion that mstest sucks 
Heck MS themselves are using xunit internally, so there's that

Comment: XUnit doesn't allow running the same theory with different data sets in parallel, which essentially prevents data driven testing.